# Session not destroyed in php after closing browser?

Tags: php, session, cookies, browser, setcookie

I am new to web develepment and I am trying to create a simple login page.
For backend I use php.
For the login I use sessions.
My problem is that sessions are not destroyed when I close the browser.
I read that sessions are destroyed automatically when closing a browser, but that is not happening in my project.

I have read many articles, I tried with

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

but this is not helping me at all, basically it does nothing.
I also read that there is a default timeout for sessions that lasts about 20 minutes and then session is closed, but it has been more than 6 hours and yet the session is not destroyed.

Sorry, if my question is stupid.
Thank you in advance! Any help or comment would be appreciated!

PS. I use Chrome browser

Comment: PHP has no way of knowing when the browser has been closed, so it can't destroy the session on the server. It uses a session cookie to hold the session ID, but this depends on the browser destroying the cookie automatically.

Comment: "_I read that sessions are destroyed automatically when closing a browser_" Firefox has something like "Restore your last open tabs on start". Enabling that will keep cookies/sessions iirc. Check if that's the same in Chrome